# Regular timer callbacks on OSX

Tags: macos, timer, scheduling

I'm trying to get a callback every N milliseconds (ideally 1) on OSX. I've set up a `CFRunLoop` and then added a timer like so:

```
const double period = 0.001;

CFAbsoluteTime now = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

CFRunLoopTimerContext context;
std::memset(&context, 0, sizeof(context));
context.info = ...;

CFRunLoopTimerRef timerRef = CFRunLoopTimerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, now + period, period, 0, 0, RunLoopTimerCallBack, &context);

// Add it to the loop.
CFRunLoopAddTimer(/* my run loop reference */, timerRef, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
```

It seems to work - my `RunLoopTimerCallback()` gets called approximately every millisecond. Except when it doesn't. The [documentation for `CFRunLoopTimerCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1543570-cfrunlooptimercreate?language=objc) says:

> The fine precision (sub-millisecond at most) of the interval may be adjusted slightly by the timer if implementation reasons to do so exist.

So I expect it to more or less work, but in practice I get delays between callbacks of up to 8 ms:

[image: delay graph]

I've tried [setting the run loop thread to real-time priority](https://github.com/adobe/chromium/blob/cfe5bf0b51b1f6b9fe239c2a3c2f2364da9967d7/base/threading/platform_thread_mac.mm#L93) but it didn't make any difference. Does anyone have any idea why I would be getting these delays? I realise this is pushing the OS quite hard and maybe it is some scheduling thing, but still... 1 millisecond isn't *that* short.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I was being an idiot. Setting real-time thread priority makes a huge difference. Here is the result:

[image: millisecond!]

And here is the code I used:

```
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include <mach/thread_policy.h>

#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

void SetPriorityRealtime()
{
    mach_timebase_info_data_t timebase;
    kern_return_t kr = mach_timebase_info(&timebase);
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        cerr << "Warning: Couldn't get timebase." << endl;
        return;
    }

    // The number of nanoseconds per tick is: 
    cerr << timebase.numer << " / " << timebase.denom << endl;

    // Set the thread priority.
    thread_time_constraint_policy ttcpolicy;
    thread_port_t threadport = pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self());

    // In ticks. Therefore to convert nanoseconds to ticks multiply by (timebase.denom / timebase.numer).
    ttcpolicy.period = 500 * 1000 * timebase.denom / timebase.numer; // Period over which we demand scheduling.
    ttcpolicy.computation = 100 * 1000 * timebase.denom / timebase.numer; // Minimum time in a period where we must be running.
    ttcpolicy.constraint = 100 * 1000 * timebase.denom / timebase.numer; // Maximum time between start and end of our computation in the period.
    ttcpolicy.preemptible = FALSE;

    kr = thread_policy_set(threadport, THREAD_TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY, (thread_policy_t)&ttcpolicy, THREAD_TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY_COUNT);
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        cerr << "Warning: Couldn't set thread policy: " << kr << endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

To be honest, I'm still not entirely sure how the `thread_time_constraint_policy` members affect things. But at least this shows it is possible. Now to do it on Windows...

Comment: Where did you generate those graphs with?

Comment: Pretty sure I just logged the callback time and graphed the difference between consecutive ones in Excel.

Comment: For anyone else reading this: This also works on iOS.

Comment: if you are curious about what all these scary numbers mean, I don't know where is proper apple documentation but there is good one about linux: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html see SCHED_DEADLINE section