# High-resolution timer in MacOS

Tags: macos, timer

I'm looking for high-resolution timer API in MacOS. In Windows there is Windows Multimedia Timers API that allows to fire events with resolution of 1ms. Is there analog in MacOS?

**Edit 1:**

I've tried `CFRunLoop` timers and it seems it gives appropriate resolution. But `CFRunLoopRun` method blocks current thread and this is not good. I want just start timer and continue with my following code. Is it possible? At now it seems MacOS lacks API for high-resolution timers that can give steady firing intervals.

Comment: OK deleted my answer.  More details required: are you using Cocoa?

Comment: At now I'm just investigating ways to have a high-resolution timer in MacOS. If Cocoa is built-in API and (ideally) provides C++ functions, it's absolutely OK.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309896/regular-timer-callbacks-on-osx